# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx.drawing'; 'networkx' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a short python script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

G = nx.DiGraph()
```

when it is executed by plain python it gave the following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/spikes/networkx.py", line 17, in <module>
    import networkx as nx
  File "/home/peng/git/mxnet-spike/python/spikes/networkx.py", line 18, in <module>
    from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx.drawing'; 'networkx' is not a package
```

What could possibly cause this? Is python interpreter defective?

Comment: can you just `import networkx` by itself? Or does it throw the same error?

Comment: just to make sure.. did you install the networkx package?

Comment: Don't name your file as networkx.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have named your file `networkx.py`. When importing `networkx` the local file has precedence over the installed package.

Just rename your `networkx.py` and make sure to delete your `__pycache__` folder if there is one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! been in JVM classpath for too long and forgot there is a thing called relative path