# What may have caused 'AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'DiGraph''?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

This is a short python program:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
```

Running it yield the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peng/git/mxnet-spike/python/spikes/networkx2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import networkx as nx
  File "/home/peng/git/mxnet-spike/python/spikes/networkx.py", line 19, in <module>
    G = nx.DiGraph()
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'DiGraph'
```

What may have caused this error? Why python fail to interpret such a simple class constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I think someone just posted this. The name of your file can't be `networkx` as it will cause issues with the package.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53966154/10708112

Edit: My apologies, you posted the same question twice.

Comment: Yeah, it was the same problem manifested differently, I may need to further expand this question